# Custom markdown parser not working properly

Tags: python

So I am making my own little script to detect some markdown notations in a variable. Now there are two issues.

- First of all, my current approach does not work when using the markdown as following (I am referring to the question mark):

```
**am I working**?
```

- Aside from that does the code look quite messy and I am pretty sure that it can be done more efficiently.

I was wondering as to what could be a better way to do what I am trying.
I want to add that I have looked for packages but these wont work in my case as I only want to allow **bold**, *italic*, underline and escaping (**bold**, _italic_ and __underline__).
My current code:

```py
description = "**one more test** _just to be sure_ \*hi\* apparently __underline broke__?"

for word in description.split(" "):
    if word.startswith("**"):    
        description = description.replace(word, f'<b>{word.replace("**", "", 1)}')
        word = word.replace("**", "", 1)
    if word.endswith("**") and not word.endswith("\**"):  
        description = description.replace(word, f'{word.replace("**", "", 1)}</b>')
        word = word.replace("**", "", 1)
    if word.startswith("*"):
        description = description.replace(word, f'<i>{word.replace("*", "", 1)}')
        word = word.replace("*", "", 1)
    if word.endswith("*") and not word.endswith("\*"):
        description = description.replace(word, f'{word.replace("*", "", 1)}</i>')   
        word = word.replace("*", "", 1) 
    if word.startswith("__"):
        description = description.replace(word, f'<u>{word.replace("__", "", 1)}')
        word = word.replace("__", "", 1)
    if word.endswith("__") and not word.endswith("\__"):
        description = description.replace(word, f'{word.replace("__", "", 1)}</u>')    
        word = word.replace("__", "", 1)
    if word.startswith("_"):
        description = description.replace(word, f'<i>{word.replace("_", "", 1)}')
        word = word.replace("_", "", 1)
    if word.endswith("_") and not word.endswith("\_"):
        description = description.replace(word, f'{word.replace("_", "", 1)}</i>')     
        word = word.replace("_", "", 1)   

print(description)
```

Comment: Why don't you look at an actual python markdown parser like https://github.com/executablebooks/markdown-it-py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should rely on `regex` expressions to be able to cover the different cases. Also, working with a clean code by defining functions and loops is better for future changes and readability.

So, to solve your special characters issue (like `?`, `!`, ..etc.), we can have the function below:

```
import re

def _check_match(text, chars, start_or_end="start", excluded_chars='()?!'):
    # check if the text ends or starts with the required characters 
    # but could have any of the excluded characters before (if start) or after (if end)
    if start_or_end == "start":
        pattern = re.compile(rf'([{excluded_chars}]*){re.escape(chars)}(.*)$')
    elif start_or_end == "end":
        pattern = re.compile(rf'(.*[^\\]){re.escape(chars)}([{excluded_chars}]*)$')
    else:
        return False, None, None
    check = re.match(pattern, text)
    if check:
        return True, check.group(1), check.group(2)
    return False, None, None

def check_match_start(text, chars):
    return _check_match(text, chars, "start")

def check_match_end(text, chars):
    return _check_match(text, chars, "end")
```

**Examples:**

```
check_match_start("**test", "**") >> (True, '', 'test')
check_match_start("(**test", "**") >> (True, '(', 'test')
check_match_end("test_?", "_") >> (True, 'test', '?')
check_match_end("test__?", "*") >> (False, None, None)
```

Then, we can have another function that loops on all the required markdowns to apply:

```
def markdown_text(text):
    markdown_criteria = [
        ("**", ["<b>", '</b>']),
        ("*", ["<i>", "</i>"]),
        ("__", ["<u>", "</u>"]),
        ("_", ["<i>", "</i>"])
    ]
    for m in markdown_criteria:
        chars = m[0]
        replacement_start = m[1][0]
        replacement_end = m[1][1]
        my_start_check, matched_special_chars, matched_text = check_match_start(text, chars)
        if my_start_check:
            text = f'{matched_special_chars}{replacement_start}{matched_text}'
        my_end_check, matched_text, matched_special_chars = check_match_end(text, chars)
        if my_end_check:
            text = f'{matched_text}{replacement_end}{matched_special_chars}'
    return text
```

**Examples:**

```
markdown_text("test__?") >> 'test</u>?' 
markdown_text("*test") >> '<i>test' 
markdown_text("**test**!") >> '<b>test</b>!'
```

**It is time to execute:**

```
description = "**one more test** _just to be sure_ \*hi\* apparently __underline broke__?"
new_description = []
for word in description.split(" "):
    new_description.append(markdown_text(word))

new_description = " ".join(new_description)
print(new_description) >> <b>one more test</b> <i>just to be sure</i> \*hi\* apparently <u>underline broke</u>?
```

This solution provides more flexibility to:

- add any other needed markdowns by simply updating `markdown_criteria` list (for example, you can add `("***", ["<b><i>", '</i></b>'])` to have bold and italic together, but make sure to add it in the beginning of the list not to be overriden by the next bold and italic criteria)
- exclude more or less special characters by simply updating the parameter `excluded_chars` in `_check_match` function

**Needed enhancements:**

This solution doesn't cover the case for an instance if you have a word starting with `**` in your phrase and there is no other word that ends with `**`, so you will end up having `<b>` without `</b>`. This can be solved if you can deal with your phrase also as a bulk in a `regex` expression instead of splitting the phrase with space and working with each word separately